# boot laptop using hardware encrypted drive from another laptop

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, encryption, uefi

I have dell e6230 with a hardware encrypted drive running linux.
Due to a problem with the old laptop, I installed the drive to another e6230,
but the new laptop will not recognize the drive during boot.

If I boot the new laptop from a usb stick, I can successfully mount the drive when I provide the endryption password.

How can I get the new laptop to boot off the encrypted drive?